# PHP associative array formation

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have two array's like:

```
$result = ["should" => 1];
$result1 = ["must" => 4, "should" => 3];
```

I need a result into single array like this:

```
["should" => 1, "must" => 4, "should" => 3]
```

I'm getting this result:

```
["should" => [1,3], "must" => 4]
```

Comment: It's not possible to have the same key twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_merge_recursive` since the `key` is duplicated so you cannot get the associate array with same key `should` as mentioned by you.

```
$result = ["should" => 1];
$result1 = ["must" => 4, "should" => 3];
print_r(array_merge($result,$result1));
```

Using `array_merge_recursive` will output you

`["should" => [1,3], "must" => 4]` which is valid associative array.